# Adding bouncycastle provider in fuse esb

Tags: bouncycastle, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

An osgi bundle in my application which runs inside fuse esb required pgp encryption provided by bouncycastle. Bouncycastle  provider should not have an impact with other applications bundles / fuse esb functionality. Since bouncycastle is not an OSGI jar, how it can be added to fuse ESB environment ?

I repackaged bouncycastle jar as an OSGI jar but it gives the signature error. I copied the jar to JDK security directory but my application bundle does not start saying bouncycastle classes not found. Same with copying to karaf external library directory.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the version of Fuse ESB (then called JBoss Fuse, now called Red Hat Fuse). I used Fuse 7.6.

I checked trivial pgp example and all I needed was to add `bcpg-jdk15on-164.jar` to `$FUSE_HOME/lib/ext` - this directory already contains `bcpkix` and `bcprov` libraries. OpenPGP support is however provided from `bcpg` library.

From OSGi point of view, you just need proper imports (or dynamic imports). No need to install any bundles, because everything is configured in `$FUSE_HOME/etc/config.properties`:

```
org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = \
    ...
    sun.*, \
    org.bouncycastle, \
    org.bouncycastle.*, \
    ...
```

If you're using JBoss Fuse 6.x, it's the same. Just `$FUSE_HOME/lib/ext` contains only `bcprov-jdk15on.jar`.

Comment: JBoss Fuse (6.0.0.redhat-024)

Comment: Did you mean imports as package imports included in org.apache.felix maven plugin as bellow ?
<Import-Package>
javax.ws.rs,
net.sf.cglib.proxy,
</Import-Package>

Comment: Yes. BTW, 6.0.0.redhat-024 is so old, that I really recommend switching to something newer.

Comment: That means copy all bouncycastle jars to $FUSE_HOME/lib/ext, edit $FUSE_HOME/etc/config.properties as shown and import org.bouncycastle packages in the bundle. Am I correct ?

Comment: It could work, but please do not consider this as supported (by Red Hat) solution, because this version is very very old.

Comment: I change as you mentioned and imported org.bouncycastle.bcpg and changed boot delegation as above with adding jar files to lib/ext directory. But my bundle with pgp code does not deploy and give bellow error.
missing requirement [504.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.bouncycastle.bcpg)(version>=1.65.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]]

Comment: Fuse (remember - you're using 6.0.0.GA) 7.6 uses BouncyCastle 1.57, so please tweak the import ranges of your bundle.

Comment: I change the versions but issue persists. I use bouncycastle maven dependency in my pom and in the manifest.mf file of generated (using maven bundle plugin) osgi bundle has bounycastle pacages as imports. Do you think it is a problem ? how do we let bundle know that to take bouncycastle dependencies from jdk ?

Comment: I got deployment success after removing removing imports of bouncycastle in my osgi bundle. But now I get "java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC" when encrypting. Is there anything else requirement to be done ?

Comment: check `security.provider.N` properties in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` - maybe you should add BC there? I'm not sure what JDK you're using.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add bouncycastle jar files to lib/ext

2) Add bouncycastle packages to bootdelegation in etc/config.properties ( as above first answer)

3) Explicitly remove bouncycastle packages from imports section of maven-bundle-plugin

```
                 <Import-Package>
                        !org.bouncycastle.jce.*,
                        !org.bouncycastle.bcpg.*,
                        !org.bouncycastle.openpgp.*,
                        !org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.*,
                        !org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.*,
                        !org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.*,
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
```

4) Import those packages in dynamic import section